# MLE estimates of regime shifted discrete process

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, discrete-data

I have a discrete process as defined,
$y_t$ = $a_1$*$x_t$ + $b_1$ + $\mathcal{N}(0,\alpha)$ when $t <= \theta$ and $y_t$ = $a_2$*$x_t$ + $b_2$ + $\mathcal{N}(0,\alpha)$ when $t > \theta$ for $t=0,1,2...N$ and $0 <= \theta <= N$. My question is, is it possible to find MLE estimates of $a_1$, $b_1$, $a_2$, $b_2$, $\alpha$, $\theta$ without brute force checking for every possible value of $\theta$(0 to N) ?

Any leads would be much appreciated.